# Android library - Need to add compile lib in both the library and main app?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am currently building an Android app where I have my main application and I have an Android library that the main application uses.

In my library I use a particular Android library compiled using gradle as follows:

```
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
```

I then add my library to the main application again using Gradle as follows:

```
compile(group: 'my.apps.package.name', name: 'app', version: "1.0.0")
```

The Rx library is only used in the Android library and not the main app, however when I run my main application I get the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "io.reactivex.Observable" on path: DexPathList...

To fix it I have to add the Rx library to my main applications gradle file as well as my libraries Gradle file but this doesn't seem right, I must be declaring the dependencies incorrectly in my Library? Can anyone point me in the right direction to achieve this?

Q: Do you use MultiDex?
A: Yes, it is enabled

```
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
```

Comment: You don't need to add this library to the main app. What you have done is correct. Do you use multidex? It seems to be an issue with multidex.

Comment: Yes multidex is enabled in the main app but not the library

Comment: Can you try compiling the library using this, " compile project(':yourlibname')
"?

Comment: That works, the other way I am creating an aar and publishing it to a repo and downloading it, this is the way it needs to be but it looks like aar doesn't include external dependencies?

Comment: Yes, that is the actual problem. It is not able to resolved the external dependencies and they are not included in the dex path. I will put it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the way you are trying to include the library.

```
compile(group: 'my.apps.package.name', name: 'app', version: "1.0.0")
```

In this way, the external dependencies are not getting resolved and included in DexPath properly.

You should be using the much simpler approach,

```
 compile project(':yourlibname')
```

This will tell Gradle to compile the module and all its external dependencies properly.

Comment: The issue is I need to publish the library to a hosting provider and as such I cannot use compile project(':yourlibname') as this is only local compilation, I create an aar of the lib and publish it, so I need to know how to include does dependencies in the aar.

Comment: Yes. You can compile the library for development purposes locally. If you intend to distribute it to others, you can obviously do so. Do let me know if you need any help on that, but that's a separate question. If this issue is resolved, please consider accepting the answer.